# Cannot able to access https apis on latest google chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.2

I have implemented TLS for my backend everthing was working fine but all of a sudden i cannot access my APIs with the updated version of chrome.

```
Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

[image]

I cannot able to figure out what went wrong here. Anyone faced this kind of issue.

Comment: are you sure the certificates are valid ?

Comment: @AshwinValento yes moreover it was working before.

Comment: What's happening in another browser?

see also: https://techcrunch.com/2018/10/08/chrome-hundreds-of-sites-to-break/?guccounter=1

Comment: @Simon in Mozilla there is no problem, earlier in chrome also i can able to access it.

Comment: @Simon thanks for the article it says chrome blocks all the site having certificate issued before June 2016 , i use openssl to create my certificate and self signed . Can you please let me know an alternative in this in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.sslforfree.com/ (uses letsencrypt to generate certificate) or https://letsencrypt.org to create new certificates for free.